# Was I supposed to perform the Blackroot ritual three times?

Tags: divinity-original-sin-2

I did the Blackroot ritual once, where Rhalic teaches me how to use Spirit Vision. Then I got my second Source Point from Hannag, at which point the Narrator suggested that I should perform the ritual again - but I did **not** do it. Instead, I went ahead and got my third Source Point.

Then the Narrator once again suggested to perform the ritual *one last time*. Almost as if implying that I already did the ritual twice.

So now with three Source Points, I performed the ritual - technically my second time doing it. Rhalic taught me Source Vampirism, and then told me to go the Nameless Isle. Siva was killed by two Voidwoken.

---

Did I miss *something* from the fact that I didn't perform the ritual three times? It seems to me like the game expected me to do it three times, but when I try to perform it a third time, the Blackroot fumes have no effect on me so I can't visit Rhalic again.

Did I miss some extra dialogue or perhaps a third skill? (I imagine Vampirism is the second skill)

Hannag mentioned that she could suck the Source out of living beings so it made sense to me that I got Vampirism as second skill. The third Source point I got was from Mordus, who said he could control the minds of others, leading me to believe that perhaps I should've obtained a third skill similar to possession or something.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the third time you perform the ritual you get source vampirism. Not sure if you're missing out on dialogue by not performing the ritual a second time though.

Comment: @Josh what was meant to happen in my second ritual then? I mean if Vision is first and Vampirism is third.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know as I did the exact same thing you did, only performing the ritual after getting the first and third source points. I suspect the second ritual only gave exposition and dialogue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't miss any powers by performing it only twice instead of three times. (In fact, it's possible to perform the ritual only one time, granting both powers at once.)

After one Source point, performing the ritual grants you Spirit Vision.

After two Source points, as you suspected, performing the ritual grants you Source Vampirism.

After three Source points, performing the ritual will simply grant some dialogue with your god. Upon your return, you'll find Meistr Siva dead.

This video shows the intended progression:

Comment: Hmph. It seems I experienced everything *except* for the Voidwoken in Rhalic's place. Although I'm not sure if it's because they simply removed that fight from the Definitive Edition.

Comment: @Omega I'm surprised you missed the Voidwoken; I played DE and experienced that fight -- although I _did_ do the ritual thrice.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 abilities that you get from the plot and I don't believe it is possible to miss them.

- Early on, back on the island of Fort Joy, you get bless.
- After speaking with Siva and performing the ritual the first time, you get spirit vision.
- After gaining your second source point, you can perform the ritual again and get source vampirism.
- After gaining 3 source points, you can perform it one last time but get no benefit (apart from xp?) and the main quest progress.

Notably you can learn to channel source from a whole lot of different characters (I think 5 or 6 different ones), not just Hannag and Mordus. It doesn't matter which ones, you won't get any different abilities.